# Errorhandling IndexError and Attribute error with DiscordPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, praw

Trying to solve errors raised by users trying to look for an image in a restricted server or 18+ server, but can't seem to figure out how to do it properly. I'm using aPraw and Discordpy

```
@bot.command()
async def redditsearch(ctx, sub):
    start_time = time.time()
    listing = []
    subreddit = await reddit.subreddit(sub)
    print(subreddit.subreddit_type)
    if sub.lower() in bannedsubs:
        await ctx.send("Banned subreddit.")
        return
    elif subreddit.over18 == True:
        await ctx.send("No NSFW subreddits.")
        return
    else:
        async for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=100):
            if submission.url.endswith(("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gifv")) and not submission.spoiler and not submission.over_18:
                listing.append(submission)
            else:
                pass
    
        random.shuffle(listing)
        post = listing[0]
        if submission.link_flair_text == None:
            await ctx.send(f"{post.title}\n{post.url}")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"[{submission.link_flair_text}] \n{post.title}\n{post.url}")
        end_time = time.time()
        await ctx.send(f"---- Took %s seconds to lookup ----" % (end_time - start_time))
```

This is the error handler.

```
@redditsearch.error
async def redditsearch_error(ctx, inst):
    if isinstance (inst, IndexError):
        await ctx.send(f"Exception raised. This probably means I failed to find an image.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Exception raised. \n\n{inst}")
```

Whenever the user attempts to fetch from a banned or restricted subreddit, it returns an AttributeError, and when it can't find an image in a public subreddit, it returns and IndexError.

How can I use an errorhandler to resolve these issues?

Comment: Is the error handler not working or what?

Comment: It's not letting me choose the errors I want. Can't find one in the documentation for Discord.py

I do get
```Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Subreddit' object has no attribute 'over18'```

and 
```Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include some `except` in your code. For that you have to modify your code a bit:

```py
@bot.command()
async def redditsearch(ctx, sub):
    try: # Must be included to use except 
    [Your code]
    except AttributeError: # except 
        await ctx.send(f"Exception raised. This probably means I failed to find an image.")
```

- `[Your code]` = Insert your code with the correct indentation.
- You can also use other `except` arguments, these are suggested to you

If you have an `IndexError` you however have to use the following:

- [discord.HTTPException](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.HTTPException) - When retrieving the message failed.

Comment: Thanks! I think you misundestood the indexerror though, thats because of the reddit thing, not Discord! I just changed it for IndexError and it works. I was hoping to be able to solve it through @redditsearch_error but this works just as fine.

Comment: Just edited my message to the correct method, I guess. You can use the error handler for `(ctx, error)`, then continue with `if isinstance(error, commands.YourError):` which will not work for these kind of errors.